# how to make li (active) and visible on click of its parent li

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

helo , i just wanted to make my li child visibile on the click of parent li,if you want to check what i want to make check out http://technologyvs.co.uk
go to the what client say section

```js
var selector, elems, makeactive,//this is for li one
    childSelector,childElems , makeChildActive;//this is for li two
    
    
    
    selector = ".parent li";
    elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    
    makeactive = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].classList.remove('active');
            this.classList.add('active');
        }
    }
    
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    
        elems[i].addEventListener("mousedown", makeactive);
    }
    
    
    childSelector = ".child li"
    childElems = document.querySelectorAll(childSelector);
    
    
    makeChildActive = function (){
    
    
    for (var j=0;j<childElems.length;j++){
      
    
        childElems[j].classList.remove('child-active');
        this.classList.add('child-active');  
         
        
    }
    
    }
    
    for(var j=0;  j<childElems.length;j++){
    childElems[j].addEventListener("mousedown",makeChildActive);
      
    }
```

```css
li.active{
    color: red;
    }
    
    
    .text li{
    visibility:visible;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        
    }
    
    
     li.child-active{
    
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 25px;     
    font-size: 25px;
    
    }
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>heloo</h1>
    <ul class="parent">
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
        <li>three</li>
        <li>four</li>
    </ul>
        
    <ul class="child">
        <li>text1</li>    
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
        <li>text4</li>
    </ul>       
    <script src="custom.js"></script>                    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can you share a little about the problem you're having? I would probably use `click` instead of `mousedown` for starters...

Comment: In jquery: `$('.parent li').click(function(){ $('.child li').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass('active') })` - The designation 'parent' and 'child' is confusing, they are not nested at all. You might want to look into nesting it and building your site according to that idea.

Comment: i just want to make my child li appear visible on the click of the parent li 
simple...

Comment: @cyedsafir yes and you can do that with the above code (the actual JS would be a lot more complex). All I am saying is that your naming convention is confusing, as there is no such relation here.

Comment: i want to make it in nested loop  , but how do i do it ?

Comment: These two ul's aren't in parent-child relation at all.... However, if i understand correctly: click on 'one' should show 'text1', etc, etc...

Comment: yes there you go , sorry i am a noob at javascript  and jquery

Comment: @somethinghere 
wht if the visiblity of the .child li is set to "hidden" how do we make it "visibile on the click of .parent li

Comment: With basic css. Just add the visibility to the .active class. Once that class gets added those CSS rules get applied.

Comment: @somethinghere can i have your email account ?  can i be your student !!

Comment: @cyedsafir The best way to learn is to do. Just find a project and start reading up (MDN is a great start). Try to earn a better reputation on stack overflow (thats a great learning experience). Join codewars.com . In short, there are better ways to become better at coding than learning from me :)

Comment: thnks man you helped me alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the simple code to do it, there are probably some edge-cases that I am not looking at but in essence this will do the trick. I added the code to a modified version of yours in the snippet below so you can see it works. I have taken out all the code that was not necessary to show how this works.

```
// A handler that allows us to remember the 'i' value when executing the click
function eventHandlerClosure(i){
    parents[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        // disable the currently active one
        var active = document.querySelector('.child li.active');
        // (if there is one)
        if(active) active.className = '';
        // add the active class to the newly selected child
        if(children[i]) children[i].className = 'active';
    }, false);
}

// select all parents and children
var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent li');
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.child li');

// attach the click events
for(var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) eventHandlerClosure(i);
```

```js
function eventHandlerClosure(i){
    parents[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var active = document.querySelector('.child li.active');
        if(active) active.className = '';
        children[i].className = 'active';
    }, false);
}

var parents = document.querySelectorAll('.parent li');
var children = document.querySelectorAll('.child li');

for(var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) eventHandlerClosure(i);
```

```css
.child li { visibility: hidden; }
.child li.active { color: red; visibility: visible; }
```

```html
 <ul class="parent">
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
 </ul>
        
 <ul class="child">
    <li>text1</li>    
    <li>text2</li>
    <li>text3</li>
    <li>text4</li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: wht if the visiblity of the .child li is set  to "hidden" how do we make it  "visibile on the click of  .parent li "

Comment: With _basic css_. Just add the visibility to the `.active` class.

Comment: it not working  :/ its showing me the active class in the  dev tools but no visibile on the page 

this is my css you are saying about ...

 li.active{
color: red;
visibility: visible;

     
}




.child li {
visibility: hidden;
}

Comment: Don't forget that `li` tagrets _any_ `li`, including the ones inside your `.parent`. I've amended the post with the added `visibility`.

Comment: its showing me a strike through on the visiblity property :/

Comment: The edited snippet above works. The elements are not visible but take up space and clicking on the 'parent' will activate the correct 'child'. I do not know why it would be striked-through, except if another rule takes precedence (like the `.active` `visibility`-rule taking precedence over the initial `visibility`-rule).